# Using typescript interface in another module file

Tags: typescript

Here is a simple interface defined in module A file:

```
interface IDirectoryLink
{
    link_title: string
    link_desc: string
}
```

And here is the class in module A file:

```
class DirectoryModel implements IDirectoryLink
{

    public link_title: string
    public link_desc: string

    constructor(fields: Object)
    {
        // Loops to populate class properties with fields values
        _.forOwn(fields, (value, key) => // Needs fat arrow to bind 'this'
        {
            if (value) { this[key] = value }
        })
    }
}
```

Later down the file, I instanciate the class:

```
let directoryModel: IDirectoryLink = new DirectoryModel(fields)
```

and then still in module A, pass the instance to a function that is in module B for validation:

```
let val = validation.modelValidator(directoryModel)
```

In module B file, here is the top of the function that is being passed the model instance to do some work on it:

```
export let modelValidator = function (directoryModel: IDirectoryLink) // cannot find name IDirectoryLink
{
//code
}
```

I was hoping that the instance passed as 'directoryModel' would be of type IDirectoryLink. But it isn't, it is of type "any" and if I add ': IDirectoryLink' as on the code above it says 'cannot find name IDirectoryLink'.

What is the proper way to be able to have the passed instance recognized as IDirectoryLink type in module B file ?
Should I import the whole module A in B that would contain exported interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your other file, it doesn't know about type 'IDirectoryLink'. You need to import that type.

That either means you need to export multiple things from module A (the interface type, and the implementation) or you need to have two modules, one containing your interface (imported by module B) and one just containing your implementation.